# Save 'data-' attributes alongwith other html content

Tags: jquery, html

I am saving a large HTML content in local storage so that some point later I can inject it back to main page. To make it small, flow looks like below

Say I have following container

```
<div class="demo-container">
     <div class="demo-box" data-save="something">Demonstration Box</div>
</div>
```

In my js I add another data attribute and save the same in some variable,

```
 $('.demo-box').data('new-attr','some more info');
 var saveDiv = $( "div.demo-container" ).html();
```

The content of the saveDiv is

```
"<div class="demo-box" data-save="something">Demonstration Box</div>"
```

The 'data-new-attr' attribute has vanished.

Is there any way by which such 'data-' attributes can co-exist with the saved HTML content

Comment: In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/x4a3bot1/) it's ok tho. You may be doing somethig wrong in somewhere else.

Comment: What is your browser and version?

Comment: Browser is chrome 39

Comment: sorry ... Dyanmically added data attributes are not getting saved to the variable. (updated my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) is not what you need to create `"data-"` attributes, but [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) :

```
 $('.demo-box').attr('new-attr','some more info');
```

> [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/na1x7a4h/)

Comment: Thanks, creating data attribute does the job. 
The comfort of skipping the 'data-' prefix while computation is lost though. Is there any reason for such behavior ?

Comment: @GAkshay What's wrong with `.attr('data-new-attr', '...');`?

Comment: nothings wrong... .data('new-attr', '...'); is shorter.